# C# winforms Toolstrip Dropdown with toolstripcontrolhost opens at (0,0) location at first time

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingnavigator

I have the bindingnavigator control with 5 items including a toolstripdownbutton. I programmatically add a toolstripcontrolhost that contains a panel to the toolstripdownbutton. When I open the dropdown first time, it shows in the location (0,0).During second and third times of dropdown opening the correct position. How do I fix this error?

```
FormTest formTest = new FormTest(); 
formTest.TopLevel = false; 
tsddbFormControl.DropDownItems.Clear(); 
formTest.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None; 
ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(formTest);     
tsddbFormControl.DropDownItems.Add(host); 
formTest.Show();
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @VahidNateghi, sorry, I am not adding the panel control, I am adding the form.

Comment: it's strange that it happens only the first time, so I doubt your code **does** locate the toolstripcontrolhost but it's a little wrong so that the first time it's failed to do its job.

Comment: @Albert anyway you need to post some code, it's hard to tell what the problem exactly is.

Comment: We need to know exactly where you have tried to add the `toolstrpcontrolhost` ...

Comment: FormTest formTest = new FormTest();
                    formTest.TopLevel = false;
                    tsddbFormControl.DropDownItems.Clear();
                    formTest.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;                    
                    ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(formTest);
                    tsddbFormControl.DropDownItems.Add(host);
                    formTest.Show();

Comment: I can repro this problem.  It is quite specific to embedding a Form with TopLevel = false, it doesn't go wrong with a control.  Impossible to debug this and find the exact reason, it quacks like a subtle initialization order issue.  Get ahead by actually using a UserControl instead of a Form.