# ToolStripControlHost defaults to (0,0) location when adding to a ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, contextmenustrip, toolstripcontrolhost

This question builds off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044855/c-sharp-winforms-toolstrip-dropdown-with-toolstripcontrolhost-opens-at-0-0-loc). What I am doing is attempting to add a DateTimePicker control to a contextmenustrip using ToolStripControlHost. What is odd is the first time I select it in the contextmenu it shows at the location (0,0)

[image: First time]

When I hover back to the option again, it displays at the right location.

[image]
I can't find where its setting the location. I've tried setting the location of the control being added but does nothing.

```
    public SampleProgram()
    {
        IntializeComponent();
        DateTimePicker sampleDatePicker = new DateTimePicker();
        sampleDatePicker.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker_OnTextChange);
        sampleDatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        datagridview1.Controls.Add(sampleDatePicker);
    }

    private void datagridview1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            datagirdview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();

            Get_Alphabetical_User_Groups(datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip, SampleContextMenu_Action);
            datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());

            GetStatusList(datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip, false, SampleContextMenu_Action);
            datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());

            GetDatePicker(datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip, SampleContextMenu_Action);
            datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Copy Cell Data", Resources.blank, SampleContextMenu_Action);
            datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
    }

    private void GetDatePicker(ContextMenuStrip dateMenu, EventHandler MenuOption_Click_Handler)
    {
        Point mouseloc = Cursor.Position;
        sampleDatePicker.Location = mouseloc;
        var datePicker = new ToolStripControlHost(sampleDatePicker);
        datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Set Followup Date to", Resources.calendar_edit, datePicker));
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your posted code has issues.  You declared the scope sampleDatePicker in the constructor, but you use that reference in the GetDatePicker method.  GetDatePicker has two parameters, but you are passing three.  It's always easier to help you if you post the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the control to the DataGridView's Control collection.  It doesn't belong there:

```
// datagridview1.Controls.Add(sampleDatePicker);
```